# Indenting long citations inside a document?

Tags: indentation, quoting

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`quoting`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting)

Suppose I have a very long sentence of law text that I need to have in my document.

And according to the XYZ law:

> Aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa aou oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa aou
>   oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa aou oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe oa
>   ao oa oa aou oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa aou oauoaeuoae uao
>   aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa aou oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa aou
>   ... aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa aou oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa
>   aou oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa ou oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe
>   oa ao oa oa aou oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa aou oauoaeuoae
>   uao aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa aou oauoaeuoae uao aaaaaa aoe oa ao oa oa
>   aou oauoaeuoae uao.

How can I indent that clearly with italics and proper citations to make it clear that it is not my writing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant with *proper citations*?

Comment: @percusse: I don't know. Is this not a bazaar where sellers augment the wants of the buyer and the buyer will select the winner? `Proper citation` in this case is a term to do things as well as possible (one answer already got into it). Sorry for me it is hard to know how to do this well, I just know that I want to improve with this thing...

Comment: Maybe it's my english that I did not get it in the first place and no, this is no bazaar here. No rewards, no competition just people helping each other.

Comment: @percusse: the whole SE is an example of a bazaar, this term is not now the normal `fruit-vegetable-type-of-thing` but the concept explained further in this book [here](http://www.amazon.com/Cathedral-Bazaar-Musings-Accidental-Revolutionary/dp/0596001088/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1322886791&sr=8-1), more [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3196/evolution-of-operating-systems-from-unix/5320#5320). This is a realization of a dream where people collaborate and help one another openly, it is not a place for Caste -system but a place for openness and honesty. I don't know, no pretending.

Comment: What happened to buyers and winners in this dream then? I don't get the relevance. Anyway no point extending this off-topic discussion. Sorry for the question.

Comment: @percusse: asker~buyer, answerer~seller. Asker is the decision-maker similarly to buyer in the open-end-market (who chooses `the winner`) -- ok the concept of winner-bazaar is an open-ended topic here (but so is the bazaaar!). This is a fuzzy analogy about SE. I do not just want to make my questions mock-exact if I do not know something. I feel it is ok to be agnostic similarly when sellers try to persuade to buy some mock-important. I feel it is many-times a problem that "sellers" try to persuade questions to totally different questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basic approach would be to use the standard `quote` or `quotation` environments, with a proper redefinition to italicize the text; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\quote\itshape
\g@addto@macro\quotation\itshape
\makeatother

\newcommand\Text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.}

\begin{document}

\Text\begin{quote}
``\Text''
\end{quote}
\Text
\begin{quotation}
``\Text''
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

If you want further customization, the [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package could be of interest.

[image]

Comment: ..precisely, thank you. How did I get lost with this command in googling?! I found a lot of things about CSquotes (never got it working). Thanks, this simplified things a lot!

Comment: Sorry but how did you get the italics there? No emph -block?

Comment: @hhh Notice that Gonzalo added `itshape` to the definitions of `quote` and `quotation`.  This is where the italics come from. `\itshape` is a switch whereas `\emph{}` is a command that takes an argument.

Comment: @AlanMunn: what is the "makeatletter" -thing? Ok, I found something [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)-- not yet fully comprehended this, thinking. A lot of small details such as `\g`, new to me.

Comment: The name of the command is `\g@addto@macro` (i.e. `\g` is not a separate part, and (as the link you found says) the @ is just a character that is reserved for internal macros.

Comment: You could mention the **quoting** package that avoids the redefinitions (at the expense of using a different environment).

Comment: @egreg: yes, I should have mentioned it. In the meantime, **lockstep** has provided an answer using his package, so I don't think it is a good idea to add it to my answer now.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That was only to solicit an answer by lockstep. :)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is answered, but I prefer the [`epigraph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph) package. Put something like the following in your preamble

```
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.90\textwidth}
```

And invoke with something like the following

```
\epigraph
{\itshape\ldots we \emph{never} experiment with just \emph{one} electron or atom or (small) molecule. In thought-experiments we sometimes assume that we do; this invariably entails ridiculous consequences\ldots}
{\emph{Are There Quantum Jumps? Part II}\\ Erwin Schr\"odinger}
```

Which will give you something like this

[image]

Comment: You can be as grumpy as you like. The package is well documented and may offer an alternative route for correct emphasis. Of course, you don't *need* to emphasise at all when its so clearly a quotation.

Comment: In addition, de-emphasis is the stadard way of emphasising in already emphasised text, so I think it's fairly clear. Of course, if you have a better way of emphasising and de-emphasising that fits here, I'll be happy to update my example. ;)

Comment: OK, sorry, I've deleted the grumpy comment. But my "moan" wasn't about the package, just the use of `\emph` for something that wasn't actually emphasis...

Comment: There was no need to delete it. If you know a better way, I really am all ears, or eyes...

Comment: I could swap out the first `\emph{...}` for an `\itshape` as mentioned above. Would that look better?

Comment: I went ahead and made that alteration. You are right that it is a bit of a misnomer to refer to the majority as emphasised.

Comment: If I had a lot of them, I'd probably define a custom `\newenvironment{esource}` for the source, including the italics, redefine with `\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{esource}`and hand-code the author as (say) `\textsc{}`.

Comment: Likewise. For one or two I'd do it like this, but for many a `newenvironment` is a better fit.

Answer (score 5):

My solution differs from Gonzalo's in two respects:

- Instead of switching between the `quote` and `quotation` environments, I use my [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package and its environment of the same name. First-line indentation is controlled by adding a blank line before the environment. Italic font is achieved with the package option `font=itshape`.
- I do no add ``` `` ``` and `''` several times in the text, but use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the beginning and the end of the `quoting` environment. This way, one doesn't have to hunt down every instance of quotings in the text if one wants the change the environment's definition. EDIT: With `quoting` v 0.1b, one may simply use the `begintext` and `endtext` options.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font=itshape,begintext=``,endtext='']{quoting}

\newcommand\Text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.}

\begin{document}

\Text
% <--- No first-line indentation of "quoting"
\begin{quoting}
\Text
\end{quoting}
% <--- No indentation after "quoting"
\Text

\begin{quoting}
\Text
\end{quoting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's really nice, any chance of getting @daleif to incorporate it into memoir? (:-). On a more serious note, how would that handle Mark's inner `\emph`?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: With `\itshape` in force, `\emph` should switch to upright text.

Comment: I really envy you your brilliance!!! {:-)